# MobileFirst 7.1 javascript adapter - how to read clob data?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

```
function getUser(userId) {

    var obj = {};

    var resultSet = WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement: getUserSQL,
        parameters: [userId]
    });

    obj = {
       name: result.resultSet[0]['NAME'],
       image: result.resultSet[0]['IMAGE'] // ???
    }

    return obj;
}
```

This returns clob.toString. I need to get the string (32K) from CLOB, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello, I've been able to solve the problem.**

I see that many people go through the same problems and I decided to share my code, I hope it helps.

**MFP 7.1 JavaScript SQL Adapter With Java**

```
function getUsuario(codigoUsuario) {

var stream = { close: function () { } };
var userInfo = {};

var connection = getConnection();
var getUsuarioSQL = 'SELECT * FROM DUAL'; // your sql

if(connection !== null && !connection.erro) {
    try {
        var stmt = java.lang.Class.forName("java.sql.PreparedStatement").cast(connection.prepareStatement(getUsuarioSQL));
        stmt.setString(1, codigoUsuario);

        var rs = java.lang.Class.forName("java.sql.ResultSet").cast(stmt.executeQuery());

        while(rs.next()) {
            userInfo.nome = rs.getString("NOME_USUARIO");
            userInfo.codigoUsuario = rs.getString("COD_USUARIO");
            var clob = rs.getClob("AVATAR");

            var reader = java.lang.Class.forName("java.io.Reader").cast(clob.getCharacterStream());
            var bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(reader);

            var line = '';
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !== null) {
                userInfo.avatar += line;
            }
        }

        return userInfo;
    } catch(erro) {
        return { erro: erro };
    } finally {
        stream.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}

return { isSuccessful: false, connection: connection };
```

}

```
function getConnection() {
    var connection = null;

    try {
        var context = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        var dataSource = java.lang.Class.forName("javax.sql.DataSource").cast(context.lookup("YourJNDI"));
        connection = java.lang.Class.forName("java.sql.Connection").cast(dataSource.getConnection());

        return connection;
    } catch(erro) {
        WL.Logger.warn("Erro: " + erro);
        return {
            erro: erro
        };
    }

    return connection;
}
```

If someone has an idea to improve the code, share it.
bye!